# Eigen Matrix, assigning a slice to the same variable triggers undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, eigen

In Eigen I have these seemingly innocuous instructions that trigger undefined behaviour.
It seems assigning the result of a matrix slicing to the same variable is unsafe. Did I miss something?

my gcc version: `gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`
my eigen version: 3.4.0

```
Eigen::MatrixXd my_mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10, 5);

Eigen::VectorXi sub_cols(3):
sub_cols(0) = 4
sub_cols(1) = 2;
sub_cols(2) = 1;

my_mat = my_mat(Eigen::all, sub_cols); // The result is not what I expect and/or triggers segfault

Eigen::MatrixXd new_mat = my_mat(Eigen::all, sub_cols); 
my_mat = new_mat; // This is fine

my_mat = my_mat(Eigen::lastN(my_mat.rows() - 1), Eigen::all); // The result is not what I expect and/or triggers segfault
Eigen::MatrixXd new_mat = my_mat(Eigen::lastN(my_mat.rows() - 1), Eigen::all);
my_mat = new_mat; // This is fine
```

Comment: This is documented here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html (not explicitly for slices, but it is essentially the same with blocks).

Comment: You can save the copy by writing `my_mat = std::move(new_mat);` (or `my_mat.swap(new_mat);`)